# How to read packets for custom classes given basic reading methods?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have implemented write/read methods for handling data in bytes for my tcp service. However, these methods can only handle basic types for example

```
public void Write(float value) 
{
    // write floats to bytes
}

public float ReadFloat()
{
    // read bytes into floats
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Each time I try to convert a custom class, I have to create a custom method for it to read/write, such as

```
public class person
{
    int age;
    string name;
    // ... more types
}
public void Write(Person p)
{
    Write(p.age);
    Write(p.name);
    // write more types...
}
```

Therefore I try to implement a generic method to handle such data structure, here is what I come up with for read, which bascially tries to access all members type, and call functions accordingly.

```
public T Read<T>(Type type)
{
    Object value = new object();
    var handler = new Dictionary<Type, Action>()
    {
        { typeof(byte)  , () => { value = ReadByte(); } },
        { typeof(bool)  , () => { value = ReadBool(); } },
        { typeof(int)   , () => { int value = ReadInt(); Console.WriteLine(value.ToString()); } },
        { typeof(string), () => { value = ReadString(); } },
        { typeof(float) , () => { value = ReadFloat(); } },
        { typeof(long)  , () => { value = ReadLong(); } }
    };



    MemberInfo [] memberInfo = type.GetMembers();
    foreach(var member in memberInfo)
    {
        switch (member.MemberType)
        {
            // filters to focus on private/public field members
            case MemberTypes.Field:
                FieldInfo field = type.GetField(member.Name);
                handler[field.FieldType]();
                Console.WriteLine($"{value.ToString()}");;
                break;


            // others like constructors, ignored
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    // code that converts into type T?
    T result = new T();
    return result;

}
```

The goal is to make this Read method accept a class type, retrieve its member's type one by one, call basic read method depending on each type to convert bytes into each type, and use these data to create an instance of such class and return it.

Essentially the problem is, I want to return a class instance depending on the input class Type argument, but I dont know how to use data returned from basic read methods to create such a class instance to return at the end. I am looking for a practical solution to it, since this saves a lot of effort to my project, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: You could either store as Object, or why not also store it as a type of T?

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar since the result class is dynamic, how to use the values returned from basic read methods to instantiate a T class?

Comment: Reinventing streams and serialization is common (usually after half-finishing custom logging and DI) developers past time. Please clarify (by [edit] of the post) if you doing that for pure entertainment or you are looking for practical solutions.